# Python 3.6.2 cx_freeze how to

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have just installed `cx_freeze` and want to use it to compile `GuessingGame.py` to `GuessingGame.exe`. I have only used functions and libraries built into python. I am using a `64 bit version of Windows 10` with Admin permissions running on a Dell Inspirion. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add code that you have tried and hasn't worked?

Comment: I haven't actually tried anything as I  don't have a clue what to even do with the code. I need a step-by-step tutorial.

Comment: The [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io) has [a tutorial](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html).  Try that out.